# For Dijkstra's algorithm, what would be a way to keep track of and store the vertices that each shortest path contains?

Tags: python, algorithm, priority-queue, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have it coded it out to update all the costs of the edges and such to complete Dijkstra's main goal of finding the shortest path from the source vertex to all other vertices.

But I what I need help on is figuring out a way to store the vertices that each shortest path contains into an array that contains each path's vertices that it passed through.

So for example let's say the shortest path from the source vertex (A) to vertex (Z) is
A -> B -> V - > Z. The shortest path goes through vertices B and V in order to get Z. I want to be able to store each of the vertices in that sequence into an array. Then place that array into a bigger list of arrays that will contain all of the sequences. The problem is that I'm not sure where to place that since the while loop below is for updating the costs of the edges.

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

class Graph:

    def __init__(self, num_of_vertices):
        self.v = num_of_vertices
        self.edges = [[-1 for i in range(num_of_vertices)] for j in range(num_of_vertices)]
        self.visited = []
        
    def add_edge(self, u, v, weight):
        self.edges[u][v] = weight
        self.edges[v][u] = weight
        
    def dijkstra(self, start_vertex):
        D = {v:float('inf') for v in range(self.v)}
        V = {v:None for v in range(self.v)}
        D[start_vertex] = 0
        
        pq = PriorityQueue()
        pq.put((0, start_vertex))
        
        AllPathsList = []
        
        while not pq.empty():
            (dist, current_vertex) = pq.get()
            self.visited.append(current_vertex)

            for neighbor in range(self.v):
                if self.edges[current_vertex][neighbor] != -1:
                    distance = self.edges[current_vertex][neighbor]
                    if neighbor not in self.visited:
                        old_cost = D[neighbor]
                        new_cost = D[current_vertex] + distance
                        if new_cost < old_cost:
                            pq.put((new_cost, neighbor))
                            D[neighbor] = new_cost
                            V[neighbor] = current_vertex          
            S = []
            u = current_vertex
            while V[u] != None:
                S.insert(0, u)
                u = V[u]
                
            S.insert(0, start_vertex)
            AllPathsList.append(S)
            
        return D, AllPathsList
        
def main():
    g = Graph(6)
    g.add_edge(0, 1, 4)
    g.add_edge(0, 2, 7)
    g.add_edge(1, 2, 11)
    g.add_edge(1, 3, 20)
    g.add_edge(3, 4, 5)
    g.add_edge(3, 5, 6)
    g.add_edge(2, 3, 3)
    g.add_edge(2, 4 ,2)
    
    D, AllPathsList = g.dijkstra(0)

    for vertex in range(len(D)):
        print("Distance from vertex 0 to vertex", vertex, "is:", D[vertex])
        print("Particular path is:", AllPathsList[vertex])
main()
```

Comment: You could store them with the coordinates, say a tuple, and when you are creating them add in it + its previous nodes denoted by the last path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual procedure is to keep track of the predecessor of each vertex.  Every time you update the cost for a vertex, you store the vertex that you got there from as its predecessor.

When you're done, you can follow the chain of predecessors from any vertex back to the source to find the shortest path to it.

Comment: And if you want all equal paths, you can store multiple predecessors - append a new one when you get an equal distance, replace the whole group with a new one when you get a shorter path.

Comment: @Matt Timmermans I added `V = {v:None for v in range(self.v)}` after initializing all the vertices to infinity and `V[neighbor] = current_vertex` after setting the neighbor to the new cost. I believe that gets what you stated in the first part. How would I follow the chain of predecessors then?

Comment: I added

`S = []
u = neighbor
while V[u] != None:
S.append(u)
u = V[u]`

after the for loop as what the top answer of this post suggests https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28998597/how-to-save-shortest-path-in-dijkstra-algorithm, but I don't believe I did it correctly.

Comment: @tridentzx you probably want to reverse `S` at the end and add `start_vertex`.  Also start at `current_vertex`, not `neighbor`.  Otherwise that looks right.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I updated the code above, and this is what the graph looks like, https://imgur.com/a/NC8QmP3, however, two of the paths got switched for some reason.  As you can see from the output that the code gives and the graph, the outputted path from vertex 0 to 3 and the path from vertex 0 to 4 are supposed to be switched.

Comment: @tridentzx paths will be found in length order.  If you need `AllPathsList` in vertex order, then do `AllPathsList[current_vertex]=S` instead of `AllPathsList.append(S)`.  You'll need to initialize it to the right length first, of course.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @MattTimmermans !